# What Does setDetailItem: Do?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C so please do forgive me if this question is silly! But I would like to know what that means.

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}
```

What these lines do in a detail view controller exactly? Does it mean that a new object, i.e `newDetailItem` is created and assigned to the already existing `detailItem`? I don't get the idea of it.

OR

Does it actually mean that this new object is is equal to the details that are present in the "detailItem" already. So, shouldn't it be written as `newDetailItem = _detailItem`, so that this new object will get the values of `_detailItem`?

This has kind of confused me a bit :(

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why dont to buy a book and start learning obj-c or look for online tutorials

Comment: I did , but this line actually confused me. So I got myself twisted..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you are showing is a typical example of a "setter"—a method that assigns a new value to a property; in this case, a property called "detailItem".

This method is generally invoked in one of two ways, either explicitly:

```
[someObject setDetailItem:someDetailItem];
```

or via dot notation:

```
someObject.detailItem = someDetailItem;
```

`_detailItem` is an instance variable, or "ivar"; it is an object-local place where the value of the property is actually stored.  This code checks to make sure the new value assigned is actually different from the old value, then assigns it and invokes a side effect, presumably updating some UI to display the new value.

Your confusion seems to stem, in part, from the name of the parameter to this method, "newDetailItem".  The name here is arbitrary, and doesn't imply that anything is being created.  It's new in the sense of being a new value for the property to have, not a new object.

Comment: Could you explain why I have to implement the setDetailItem method to change the DetailItem object, where i don't need any method for any other objects such as NSMutableString....

Comment: @Aminul Its just to have an updated value .. this method just checks if the old one has the updated value, else to put in the new value so that it remains updated. So after this process, the view is configured according to this value.

Answer (score 1):

This method is **setting** the new value `newDetailItem` to `_detailItem`.

In this statment `if (_detailItem != newDetailItem)` it is checking if both are same object or not, by comparing there memory locations.

In `_detailItem = newDetailItem;` newDetailItem that is passed as `id` is put to `_detailItem`.

*In case of ARC: The value is retained/copy as in ARC this is not specified.*

You are accessing your property directly by `_detailItem`. You have a property called `detailItem` in your class.

And then calling a method `configureView`.